# Changing The "Access Google Analytics" Button Text

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I have an admin page in my site where I implemented Google Analytics Embed. Everything works fine, but I want to translate the login button text:

[image]

This button is called by `gapi.analytics.auth.authorize()`

My function looks like this atm:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    userInfoLabel: 'Logged in as: ',
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'CLIENTID'
  });
```

I have checked the Developers Guide where I've found `userInfoLabel:` which is replacing the text "`You are logged in as:`", but I haven't found anything about how to replace the text on the login button.

I was working with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [Third party visualizations Demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/).

My page looks like this if logged in:

[image]

And looks like this if not logged in:

[image]

Questions are:

1. How can I replace the "Access Google Analytics" text?
2. How can I set
   the value of the container to `display:none;` when the user is not
   logged in. (container id: `'container'`)

---

EDIT:

I tried to check for `gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()` for the part where I want to check if a user is logged-in or not, but it always gives `false`.

Comment: I am not sure that you can but please post it if you figure it out :)

Comment: Of course I will, since I haven't found anything on the web about it yet, I'd really like to give ppl help here at SO :)

Comment: The embedded API isn't Open source (yet I have been trying to work with the team to get them to open source it) if it was we could dig around in the code.

Comment: TIP: enable maps api in your project on google developer console if you want to use the Map graph or it wont work.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about it, enabled Google Static Maps API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) haven't found an option that allows the button text to be changed

regardless, changing with `css` or even `javascript` should be fine

so long as it gives the desired result

2) rather than hiding the `container` *when the user is not logged in*...

--> hide the `container` by default

then un-hide when the user logs in, using the `signIn` event

e.g.

```
<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

<div class="hidden" id="container"></div>

<script>
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    userInfoLabel: 'Logged in as: ',
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'CLIENTID'
  });

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('signIn', function() {
    // un-hide container
    document.getElementById('container').className = '';
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check the [link](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) in the question about the third party visualizations demo, the `gapi.analytics.auth.authorize` puts the button in the `'embed-api-auth-container'` div, and you want to hide the `'container'` div. If I change the `'container'` to the desired class name, will it work? (Sorry, can't check the code atm.)

Comment: as for which container to specifically hide, i'm not exactly sure, was just going by the question --> _How can I set the value of the container to display:none; when the user is not logged in. (container id: `'container'`)_ -- regardless, you should be able to hide / un-hide any container you want -- if you need more specific help, add relevant code / html to the question...

Comment: If it is good for you, I will update the question _tomorrow morning_ with the whole structure of the container that has the button.

Comment: +1 for the `signIn` event, actually your first revision did the trick with the `.style.display=` event, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've found an another way to replace the text on that button, but I won't accept my answer, hopefully someone could find the real answer to the question.

What I did is actually a hack that I use in some situations (like when you have a third party library that is not Open Source as DalmTo said).

I have found, that the button is in a `<span>` element with a class defined:

```
<span class="gapi-analytics-auth-styles-signinbutton-buttonText">Access Google Analytics</span>
```

So I decided to use CSS to replace the text:

```
span.gapi-analytics-auth-styles-signinbutton-buttonText {
    visibility: hidden;
}
span.gapi-analytics-auth-styles-signinbutton-buttonText:after {
    content: 'Bejelentkezés a Google Analyticsbe';
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
```

And now, ta'da:

[image]