# Google Analytics Embed Api with new google login authorization flow -i.e Google Identity ( 2022 )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have been trying to integrate google analytics embed api in my react application by using traditional gapi approach but I am getting this error from google

> "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."

I get it that newly created client ids won't work with gapi as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

> We are discontinuing the Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web. The library will be unavailable for download after the March 31, 2023 deprecation date. Instead, use the new Google Identity Services for Web.
> By default, newly created Client IDs are now blocked from using the older Platform Library, existing Client IDs are unaffected. New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can set `plugin_name` to enable use of the Google Platform Library.

I have also tried to add **plugin_name** but it stills gives the same error . I have also tried this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-analytics-api but it also uses gapi so it is outdated as well ( but works with old client ids ).
Here is the react-use-analytics-api code I have followed https://justinmahar.github.io/react-use-analytics-api/useAuthorize

Now my question is how can I integrate google analytics embed api in my react project with new google authorization flow that is Google Identity .

Answer (score 0):

First off the [Google analytics embedded api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1) was designed to work with the Google analytics core reporting api which is Google analytics api version 3.

There is also the google analytics reporting api which is version 4.  The embedded api was never upgraded to work with that.  both of those apis access only UA analytics

Now we have the Google analytics data api, which is for google analytics GA4.  Universal analytic will stop recording data January 2023.

The Javascript sign in library that it works with has also been upgraded and the old library no longer works.

I guess what i am saying is that you should not bother trying to use the Embedded api its way out of date.

That being said will contact the team to see if they have any plans to upgrade it in the future.

Comment: I have heard back from the team there is currently no plans to upgrade the embedded API to support ga4 or fix any issues created by changes to google JavaScript sign-in

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Actually my team is working on a project related to SEO , where the purpose of using google analytics embed api is to show a list of their analytics profiles [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list) and a list of their goals [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list) . By using  **Google analytics data api** instead can we still manage to authorize user and get their profiles and goals list ? if yes then how can we achieve such goal

Comment: If you want to manage a users ga4 account you would need to go though [Google analytics admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1)  How you do that would depend upon the programming language you are using.  The team is working on samples currently

Comment: @DalmTo I can't find any documentation to get list of goals and profiles in [Google analytics admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1) . I am confused because all I want is to display a button to client [this button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927382/changing-the-access-google-analytics-button-text) where they can authorize and after that I show them their profiles and goals list but through **Google analytics data api** and  **Google analytics admin api** I can't find a way of achieving such goal . Should I wait for the updated docs ?

Comment: GA4 is not the same as UA analytics.   There are no “goals” in GA4, just conversions.

Comment: @DalmTo I have created another issue you might be familiar with [How to fetch Users Google My Business Data from Google My business Api ( 2022 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73082828/how-to-fetch-users-google-my-business-data-from-google-my-business-api-2022)