# How to fetch Users Google My Business Data from Google My business Api ( 2022 )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-my-business-api

I want to show user a login with "google business" button on my React.js application where user can verify via their google account and after verifying user can see their google business data like number of phone calls , number of website visits, number of request directions and business reviews. I found this documentation https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businesscalls/rest/v1/locations.businesscallsinsights/list to get number of calls but it requires **parent=locations/*** as shown below ( I have no idea what it is )
`https://mybusinessbusinesscalls.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=locations/*}/businesscallsinsights`.

The thing is I don't have any businesses whom data I would like to see , I just want to show users theirs business data . How can I achieve such goal
-Authorize User
-Get Google My business Data On Behalf Of User
-Required fields are listed above

Any help is highly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this using this API you need to create an app in [google dev console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/).
Then you need to ask a user for permission to connect your app to his account.
More about OAuth [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/oauth-overview)